# Getting output from a list of strings

Tags: python-2.7

This is a list:

```
print a[0].split('\n')
['1 test 1', '2 test 2', '3 test 3', '4 test 4', '5 test 5']
```

and I simply want to extract every number in the begining of every string, and append it to a new list.

I used:

```
filter(re.compile("1.").match,a[0].split('\n'))
['1 test 1']

filter(re.compile("^1 ").match,a[0].split('\n'))
['1 test 1']
```

But they doesn't work, does anyone can help.

The expected output should be:

```
filter(re.compile("SOMETHING").match,a[0].split('\n'))
['1']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
res = []
for i in your_list:
    res.append(i.split()[0])
```

Comment: @Mohamed, any feedback? was my answer helpful?

Comment: Unfortunately not, my problem is not appending an item to a list, it's getting the correct Regex which will just find and pop a specific string from a list of strings in a list.

Comment: well, according to your example in question, my code does the thing=) maybe you should give another example? and is it obligatory to use regex when you can solve problem without them?